# Spring Batch RepositoryItemReader With Native Query Not Working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I just want to execute a native query method in spring data jpa which has no parameters.

**Issue 1** : With No Parameters for native query method

```
@Repository
public interface Repoclass extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>
{

    @Query(value = "SELECT id, name, town, datecheck\r\n"
            + " FROM public.employee",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Employee> getEmp();
```

Repository Item reader :

```
@Bean
    public RepositoryItemReader<Employee> readdb()
    {
        RepositoryItemReader b = new RepositoryItemReader<Employee>();
        b.setRepository(repoclass);
        b.setMethodName("getEmp");
        return b;
    }
```

If i use above code i'm getting sort should not be null error.

**Issue 2**-- with pageable as native query parameter

```
@Repository
public interface Repoclass extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>
{

    @Query(value = "SELECT id, name, town, datecheck\r\n"
            + " FROM public.employee",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Employee> getEmp(Pageable p);
}
```

```
@Bean
    public RepositoryItemReader<Employee> readdb()
    {
        RepositoryItemReader b = new RepositoryItemReader<Employee>();
        b.setRepository(repoclass);
        b.setMethodName("getEmp");
        Map<String, Direction> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("id", Direction.ASC);
        b.setSort(map);
        return b;
    }
```

**Issue 3** -- Native Query with parameters

```
@Repository
public interface Repoclass extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>
{

    @Query(value = "SELECT id, name, town, datecheck\r\n"
            + " FROM public.employee where id=:id",countQuery = "select count(*) FROM public.employee  where id=:id",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Employee> getEmp(Integer id,Pageable p);
}
```

```
@Bean
    public RepositoryItemReader<Employee> readdb()
    {
        RepositoryItemReader b = new RepositoryItemReader<Employee>();
        b.setRepository(repoclass);
        b.setMethodName("getEmp");
        List<Object> t = new ArrayList<>();
        t.add(1);
        b.setArguments(t);
        Map<String, Direction> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("id", Direction.ASC);
        b.setSort(map);
        return b;
    }
```

Tried every possible way But Nothing is worked out. My Requirement is to call a native query method which has no parameters using repository item reader. Could you please Anyone help with this.

Tried every possible way But Nothing is worked out. My Requirement is to call a native query method which has no parameters using repository item reader. Could you please Anyone help with this.

Comment: `If i use above code i'm getting sort should not be null error.`: From the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/data/RepositoryItemReader.html) of the repository item reader, you need to provide a `Sort`. Your issue is a Spring Data issue, not Spring Batch issue. You can only set the method name on the `RepositoryItemReader`, so you need to  make sure your Spring Data repository is working as expected before using it in a `RepositoryItemReader`

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, Thanks for your reply, i pointed the same thing in the issues above. I want to execute native query  method of no parameters with repository item reader. Something i’m missing here, but its not an issue with spring data i feel, if this is could you please tell me how can i execute that